# How to cancel the consumer method in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

How can I cancel the execution of a Consume method of an `IConsumer<>`? I tried to create a cancellation token and use another thread to trigger the cancellation, and I can get a `ConsumerCancelledException`, but I could not handle the Fault<> message. E.g.

- I have  a `MyDataConsumer: IConsumer<MyData>` and `MyDataFaultConsumer: IConsumer<Fault<MyData>>: IConsumer<Fault<MyData>>`
- The `IConsumer<MyData>` throws an `ConsumerCancelledException`
- The failed message went into the `MyData_error` queue, but it did not go to the `MyDataFault` queue

However, if I directly throw an exception in my `MyDataConsumer`, my fault consumer can get the data. It seems the ConsumerCancelledException is handled differently than other exceptions.